# Measuring density for three dimensional data (in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, distribution

I have a dataset consisting of a large collection of points in three dimensional euclidian space. In this collection of points, i am trying to find the point that is nearest to the area with the highest density of points.

So my problem consists of two steps:

- 1: *Determine where density of the distribution of points is at its highest*
- 2: *Determine which point is nearest to the point found in 1*

Point 2 i can manage, but i'm not sure how to solve point 1. I know there are a lot of functions for density estimation in Matlab, but i'm not sure which one would be the most suitable, or straightforward to use.

Does anyone know?

---

*My command of statistics is a little bit rusty, but as far as i can tell, this type of problem calls for multivariate analysis. Someone suggested i use multivariate kernel density estimation, but i'm not really sure if that's the best solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Density is a measure of mass per unit volume.  On the assumption that your points all have the same mass then you are, I suppose, trying to measure the number of points per unit volume.  So one approach is to divide your subset of Euclidean space into lots of little unit volumes (let's call them voxels like everyone does) and count how many points there are in each one.  The voxel with the most points is where the density of points is at its highest.  This is, of course, numerical integration of a sort.  If your points were distributed according to some analytic function (and I guess they are not) you could solve the problem with pencil and paper.

You might make this approach as sophisticated as you like, perhaps initially dividing your space into 2 x 2 x 2 voxels, then choosing the voxel with most points and sub-dividing that in turn until your criteria are satisfied.

I hope this will get you started on your point 1; you seem to be OK with point 2 so I'll stop now.

**EDIT**

It looks as if `triplequad` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: And do you know of a function in Matlab that does what you're describing (group into voxels, count, iterate, etc.)?

Comment: I have found a *lot* of probability density functions though, but i don't know which one would be best (or if they're even applicable to this kind of problem). So far I haven't been able to find any kind of straightforward, simple, function for density estimation.

Comment: Wow, this raises a whole bunch of new questions :). I'll be asking them in a new topic, or we would have to discuss this all in the comments. Thanks for the quick answer!